# Where I download plugin StrongOD 0.3.4.639?

Tags: ollydbg

I want plugin for OllyDbg - strongOD 0.3.4.639 version. Where I find it for download? Thank for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about that version but you can find the latest version (0.4.8.892) here

https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.2028

For more information about OllyDbg plugin system see ***[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574155/how-to-setup-plugins-for-ollydbg-2-x-x)*** and ***[this](http://www.ollydbg.de/Help/i_Plugins.htm)***

Comment: Thank you very much. So, how I use it? I thought that will install it, but its only .dll file, so how I get it into OllyDbg? Many thanks.

Comment: You should setup your OllyDBG plugin directory and just place the dll in that directory. Olly will load the plugin automagically.